# How do you add lines to /etc/default/grub so they're reflected in /boot/grub/grub.cfg?

Tags: grub2

My question is about how to add a few lines to the `/etc/default/grub` file so that it is automatically reflected each time `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is regenerated.  The details:

I'm running ubuntu on a Macbook Pro 8.2 and one of the things that I had to do to get it to run correctly was alter the grub.cfg so that it only loads one of the two graphics cards.  To turn off one of the cards I added the text concerning i915 in the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT /etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.lvds_channel_mode=2 i915.modeset=1 i915.lvds_use_ssc=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

The problem is that I must also have the following adding to `/etc/grub.cfg`:

```
  outb 0x728 1
  outb 0x710 2
  outb 0x740 2
  outb 0x750 0
```

Which I've added in context in `grub.cfg` as so:

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-1e8685ef-b6a8-4bf3-abb8-62d0212cea7c' {
recordfail
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
insmod part_gpt
insmod reiserfs
outb 0x728 1
outb 0x710 2
outb 0x740 2
outb 0x750 0
set root='hd0,gpt4'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  21c34907-4da5-4356-b1c8-a5d2747411ed
else...
```

How can I add this to the `/etc/default/grub` file so that I don't have to manually add it to the `grub.cfg` every time Ubuntu updates?  Currently it appears as if each time Ubuntu updates it regenerates the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file from the `/etc/default/grub` file and it'd be helpful if these four lines could be included as well.

Answer (score 2):

Do not edit the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file. Edit the `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` file:

Add your commands to the

```
  cat << EOF
    insmod gzio
EOF
```

section, so it should read:

```
  cat << EOF
    insmod gzio
    outb 0x728 1
    outb 0x710 2
    outb 0x740 2
    outb 0x750 0
EOF
```

This file is sourced every time `update-grub` is run, and it is rarely overwritten by updates. (Or at least it will ask when you update whether you want to update this file or keep your modified version.)

Answer (score 0):

You must edit the configuration scripts directly. There's no way to add `outb 0x728 1` to the grub.conf file, since the scripts that sources the variables there doesn't know how to manage these entries. This is said in the info pages:

> For more detailed customisation of 'grub-mkconfig''s output, **you may
>   edit the scripts in '/etc/grub.d' directly**.  '/etc/grub.d/40_custom' is
>   particularly useful for adding entire custom menu entries; simply type
>   the menu entries you want to add at the end of that file, making sure
>   to leave at least the first two lines intact.

So, what to do, for the linux entries, you may want to edit the `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` file, very carefully. You may look for the `linux ()` function and study it's internals. The whole thing is very complex and I wouldn't touch it without a backup. You can see the output of the file just running `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` in your shell, then look where you want to add your special lines, edit it, execute it again and see if you are happy with the results.

Answer (score -1):

To be honest, easiest way would be to backup the 2 files and each time Ubuntu updates, you run a script as root ofc:

```
#!/bin/sh
rm /boot/grub/grub && /boot/grub/grub.cfg
cp /directory/grub /boot/grub/
cp /directory/grub.cfg /boot/grub/
```

One thing, change `/directory/` to your directory to the files :)