# how do I install GKSU or other program to edit as root to save changes in grub file at /etc/default to enable nomodeset bootup?

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, recovery-mode, etc, nomodeset

### 20 March 2019 inquiry

In November I got a response to [How do I fix a frozen black screen on Lubuntu startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077616/how-do-i-fix-a-frozen-black-screen-on-lubuntu-startup) from karel to consult https://askubuntu.com/tags/nomodeset/info

I initially opened grub from etc/default and changed:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
```

It wouldn't let me save the changes though! It opened it in leafpad, but I didn't have the permissions!

Karel's followup comment suggested I run it as root to get permission via this command in the terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

I am sure most would recommend getting familiarity with the terminal. I did figure it out, because I changed it (keyboard arrows only to navigate, no mouseclicks!) and upon exiting it prompted me to save, and I did, and then ran `sudo update grub afterward as both the wiki and Karel said to.

I was searching more on the topic and found [How to edit GRUB file at /etc/default/](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294069/how-to-edit-grub-file-at-etc-default) where in 2013 someone recommended using something called gksu to edit as root. Is this still around? I couldn't find it in Synaptic Package Manager when I searched it.

I'm looking for alternative means of root editing (perhaps via Leadpad, which is how grub opened by default when I double clicked it) which are a little easier on the eyes and mind than editing in the terminal is.

For now I am going to reboot and see if this fixed things. Would anyone know about the issue raised at [How do you add lines to /etc/default/grub so they're reflected in /boot/grub/grub.cfg?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310435/how-do-you-add-lines-to-etc-default-grub-so-theyre-reflected-in-boot-grub-gru) and if there is some special considerations for /boot/grub/grub.cfg? in selecting what graphic drivers to run at startup?

I get this message when I do "Advanced Options" and then "Recovery Mode" then "Resume Boot"

> some graphics drivers require a full graphical boot and so will fail when resuming from recovery

I assume doing this 'nomodeset' is similar, except rather than the drivers failing, they don't try to initiate at all, so I could do a regular startup. I will be trying this now and will update with results.

Comment: The text editor Kate will ask you for a sudo password when trying to write a file you don't have write permissions on. It will then elevate its permissions to write the file, so no need to run it as root in the first place (which `sudo nano`, `gksu leafpad` etc. do). `gksu` and `gksudo` are not available in the repositories anymore and will probably never come back.

Answer (score 1):

### `gksu` is deprecated and no longer available.

Many people recommend command line tools for administration tasks, for example

```
sudo nano filename
```

But if you really need a program with a graphical user interface, there are solutions:

- If the program is prepared for it

  ```
  GUI-program
  ```

  or select the program via the menu or `dash` and you will be prompted for password
- `pkexec GUI-program`
- `sudo -H GUI-program`

---

Never use plain `sudo GUI-program` because it can damage your userID's configuration files.

---

If you are using Wayland (instead of the old Xorg), there is more complication, described at the following link,

[Why don't gksu/gksudo or launching a graphical application with sudo work with Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w/961978#961978)